# Why does some part of acquired signals repeat at the beginning and ending of signal?

Tags: labview, nidaqmx, daq-mx

I'm acquiring some pulses which repeat at certain intervals. Hardware is Advantech pci1710 (it is like NI multifunctional pci cards), software used is Labview 2013.

**The problem is:** at the beginning and ending of pulses I see some added pulses which I'm not sending to the device! What are these pulses and their origin and how to fix it?

Pulses screenshot >

[image: Messy signals]

Red signal and white signal are both about 500 HZ Square wave which repeat one after each other (number of pulses sent to each channel is limited. They are in fact pulses generated using Arduino to control a servo motor driver).

[program written in labview](https://uploadfiles.io/qny6b)

sampling pulses vi has two signals sampled and are default values on the graph.
readback vi has one signal sampled and is the default value on the graph.

on the read back vi I have written a code to count the number of pulses .

**what I found is that:** 
I'm sending 2000 pulses but each pulse is divided into 3 parts , the first part and the third part vary and the middle pulse is almost fixed .  if I sum the divided parts it is 2007 pulses and near to the 2000 pulses I send .

Comment: I thought the origin may be the sample and hold capacitor not discharging so pulled down the input of the card . buffered the  signals to the card but non of them fix the problem .

Comment: It is very hard to help you without seeing code and a better image where the problem can be seen. Is your problem in acquiring or sending? How are you sure that the problem is not in the generated pulses from the Arduino. How much added pulses do you see?

Comment: I checked the signals using an oscilloscope  and all signals were fine . so the problem is in acquiring the signals . I haven't count the added pulses but they are generated when signal is rising from zero to 5 volts and when it is dropping from 5 volts to zero .  I don't have access to the written program and a better picture right know but i will upload them tomorrow

Comment: I will wait for the code, but I would be quite surprised if this problem comes form the labview program (usually stuff gets missing not added in software). I would sooner expect wrong card settings (debouncing, etc), can you read out the same data with the manufacturer program (guess DAQnavi SignalMeter or DataLogger should be able to do this?) and see if there the problem is present or not?

Comment: I edited the question and added the written  program in Labview. you can see the pulses in details now.